# C++: Open Multi Methods vs Double Dispatch, is it in the newer standard?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

Is Open multi-methods integrated into the newer C++ standards?  If so, what is it or where can I find it documented?

I'm reading Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 655, in which Double Dispatch is presented.  Stroustrup claims the technique is intrusive and he prefers a simple function as a solution to the problem and then references [Pirkelbauer,2009].  I did a search on Pirkelbauer and it looks like he created the Open Multi-Methods framework, but not sure if that made it into the newer standards.  Stroustrup also claims it did not make it into C++11 standards.

Side note: I'm also a bit curious why he didn't mention a solution using `dynamic_cast<>` to the problem that double dispatch solves.

Appreciate your guidance.  Thanks

Comment: Unless you've profiled your code and found double-dispatch to be a performance impediment, there is no reason to avoid double-dispatch.  If you have found it to be a performance bottleneck, then CRTP may be of interest.

Comment: In answer to your second question Dynamic cast is slow and dangerous.

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for from pirkelbaur https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1289971.1289993 sus link is sus. Here is the title. `Open multi-methods for c++`

Comment: @Eljay Stroustrups explains how tedious it can be to construct all the functions, especially as the argument count increases.  Also a change is required for all the classes.  I don't think performance was mentioned.

Comment: @Taekahn I see an implementation at https://github.com/jll63/yomm11, but it's deprecated in favor of a D version.  I was curious if the solution ever made it into the newer standards.

Comment: No proposal of multimethods has been accepted into the standard.

Comment: @andyg I just received an email from Stroustrup to the same effect.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is no. If it ever makes into the standard, I should be very surprised. Most of the functionality can be implemented with a library such as yomm, No, yomm11 is not deprecated in favour of a D version, it is deprecated in favour of [yomm2](https://github.com/jll63/yomm2) which is very much a C++ library.

Comment: YOMM11 is not deprecated in favor of a D version. It is superseded by YOMM2 (https://github.com/jll63/yomm2), also a C++ library. Indeed There is a D version as well: https://code.dlang.org/packages/openmethods - but it does not replace any iteration of YOMM.

Answer (score 1):

No proposal of multimethods has been accepted into the standard.  Received from B.S. via email